# How to place floating action button to right bottom of screen inside Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ScrollView` at the top, inside that I have a `ConstraintLayout`. Setting height to `match_parent` doesn't work in ConstraintLayout so the height doesn't match the screen. Inside my `ConstraintLayout` I have a floating action button and it doesn't stay at the right bottom of the screen, but it stays at the right bottom of `ConstraintLayout`.

Image of my screen

[image]

How can I make the floating action button stay at the right bottom of the screen?

Comment: share xml code...

Comment: You need to start with the ConstraintLayout. Then you put the floating button and the scrollview into it. So the floating button will not scroll

Comment: you cannot do it like this. The FAB must be outside of the CL, because the CL might not fit the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is that I put the FAB on the same level as the app bar, making it independent of the content itself presented on that page (using coordinator layout).

Try to put the FAB on the app bar level instead of content level. See if it works.

Answer (score 8):

If your FAB is inside constraint layout try like this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/contactBtn"
    android:layout_width="53dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
```

This Worked For me..

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `CoordinatorLayout` instead contraints layout like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

    ........
    ........
</RelativeLayout> 

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

for more go through [this tutorial.](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/)

Answer (score 0):

try putting the FAB in the XML in the same level of the parent of the constraint layout. That should fix it!
Not only that, make sure that your parent layout is not linear layout!

Comment: Shouldn't that be a comment?